# Composer package versioning with git

Tags: composer-php

I am using git to manage my composer packages' versions.
Whenever I update my package to a new version, I create a new tag in git ("v1.0.0")

When I try to update, it downloads from cache.
I also tried removing the package and re-install, but still it would install older version.

this is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://example.com/packages"
    }],

    "require": {
        "ynaxon/counter": "dev-master#v1.0.0"
    }
}
```

My package repository is built via Satis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is pinned to v1.0.0, thats why Composer always fetches from cache.
When you use tags you can omit dev-master and just use the respective semantic versioning like:

```
"ynaxon/counter": "^1.0"
```

Composer will now update your package whenever it finds a new tag in the v1 range.

Also make sure that Satis updates the package correct and that the package is available in Satis.

Comment: perfect! is there a way to avoid having to re-build satis each time a package version is updated?

Comment: The satis docs recommend a cronjob: "what you would typically do is run this command as a cron job on a server. It would then update all your package info much like Packagist does."